# How to design a foreach(){...} not to fail on a "could not find function readWave" error?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, wav

I am trying to read multiple **`.WAV`** files, using a **`readWave()`** function, for processing.

It was all working fine, till I imported each `.WAV` file sequentially, and then processed them one by one. But, while trying to make it run in a parallel mode of execution, I tried to use **`foreach(){...}`** and ran the code. It says

> `Error in { : task 1 failed - "could not find function "readWave""`

Can anyone help here please?
There was no other change than for changing to foreach.

```
foreach ( i = 1:nfiles, combine = cbind ) %dopar% {  
                               input_file_name = filist[1]   
   input_wave_file = readWave( input_file_name )
   Preprocessing(              input_file_name ) # this is my later defined fun()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This kind of error message nearly always means that you need to use the foreach `.packages` option (to make the workers load a package) or the `.export` option (to send a local function to the workers). In this case, the workers probably need to load the `tuneR` package which defines the `readWave` function:

```
foreach (i=1:nfiles, combine=cbind, .packages='tuneR') %dopar% {  
  input_file_name = filist[1]   
  input_wave_file = readWave(input_file_name )
  Preprocessing(input_file_name)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it was because i was in a for loop and it wasnt recognizing the function inside the loop, and yes, I had obviously defined the package before trying to use the function@Steve Weston. I now managed to resolve it.